# Function declared in a loop contains unsafe references to variable(s) 'regionOptions' no-loop-func

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

The loop works when I don't assign regionOptions to regions.data. However when I do it throws the above error. I have no idea how else to proceed any pointers would be greatly appreciated - I am very new to all of this. Many thanks!

```
function AddOfficeForm(props: CreateOfficeFormProps): JSX.Element | null {

    let dropDownItems = [];
    let regionOptions: string | any[] = [];
    const region_id = uuidv4();

    // TODO: fetch actual available regions from API
    axios.get(ApiEndPoints.getAllRegionsForUser + firebaseContext.firebase.auth().currentUser?.uid)
        .then((regions: AxiosResponse<Array<string>>) => {
            regionOptions = regions.data;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
    history.push("/");

    const onTargetSelect = (selected: string) => {
        setSelectedRegion(selected);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < regionOptions.length; i++) {
        dropDownItems.push(<Dropdown.Item key={regionOptions[i]} eventKey={i.toString()} onSelect={() => onTargetSelect(regionOptions[i])}>{regionOptions[i]}</Dropdown.Item>)
    }
```

Comment: At least closely related: [*Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: Also at least closely related: [*How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think TypeScript is complaining about that code because when the `onSelect` event handler is called, `regionOptions[i]` is evaluated *then*, and you've said that `regionOptions[i]` is `string | any[]` (it might be a `string`, or it might be an `any[]`). `onTargetSelect` requires that its argument be a `string`, but if `regionOptions` is `any[]`, then `regionOptions[i]` is `any`, not `string`. Or it may be that combined with the fact that you reassign `regionOptions` after the loop.

I suspect you meant `(string | any)[]` (or `Array<string | any>` instead of `string | any[]`, but even if so, you'd still have the issue that `regionOptions[i]` could be `any` rather than `string`. From your `onTargetSelect` parameter type, it should just be `string[]` (if you even give it an explicit type, which you often don't need to).

But the other problem is that `regionOptions` will be `[]` as of your loop and you'll never push anything to `dropDownItems`. Fundamentally, you shouldn't be using `regionOptions` outside the fulfillment handler on the `axios` call, because you don't have that data yet. (More in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron).) Once you do have the data, the idiomatic way to map those strings to `Dropdown.Item` instances is via `map`.

For instance:

```
function AddOfficeForm(props: CreateOfficeFormProps): JSX.Element | null {

    const region_id = uuidv4();

    const onTargetSelect = (selected: string) => {
        setSelectedRegion(selected);
    };

    // TODO: fetch actual available regions from API
    axios.get(ApiEndPoints.getAllRegionsForUser + firebaseContext.firebase.auth().currentUser?.uid)
        .then((regions: AxiosResponse<Array<string>>) => {
            // *** Build dropDownItems here
            const dropDownItems = regions.data.map((value, index) =>
                <Dropdown.Item key={value} eventKey={index.toString()} onSelect={() => onTargetSelect(value)}>{value}</Dropdown.Item>
            );
            // Do something with `dropDownItems` here
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    history.push("/"); // <== Unclear whether this should be here or in the fulfillment handler
```

You haven't shown what you want to do with `dropDownItems`, but note that your function can't *return* them (more in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)), because it returns before the `axios` call completes and gives you the data for them.